# Unable to collect substring from a string

Tags: c#, string, substring

I am extracting a substring from a string that comes from a word file. But I am getting an error of `index out of range` even if the starting and ending index of substring is less then the length of the string.

```
for(int i=0;i<y.Length-1;i++)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(y[i], @"^[A]"))
    {       
        NumberOfWords= y[i].Split(' ').Length;

        if (NumberOfWords > 5)
        {
            int le = y[i].Length;
            int indA = y[i].IndexOf("A");
            int indB = y[i].IndexOf("B");
            int indC = y[i].IndexOf("C");
            int indD = y[i].IndexOf("D");

            //if (indD > 1 && indC > 1)
            //    breakop2 = breakop2 + '\n' + '\n' + y[i].Substring(indC, indD);

            if (indC > 1 && indB > 1)
                breakop1 = breakop1 + '\n' + y[i].Substring(indB, indC);

            if (indB > 1)
                sr = y[i].Substring(indA, indB);
            else
                sr = y[i];

            breakop = breakop +'\n'+'\n'+ sr;
            Acount++;
            //textBox1.Text = s[i];
            check1 = check1 + '\n' + '\n' + y[i];
            //i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`String.Substring(int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) doesn't take a start index and an end index (as it does in Java); it takes a start index and a *length*. So perhaps you want:

```
sr = y[i].Substring(indA, indB - indA);
```

But you should *also* check that `indB` is greater than `indA`. (You need to work out how you want this to behave if `B` comes before `A`, basically.)

You'd also need to apply the same behaviour for the `Substring(indB, indC)`.

Answer (score 9):

The [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) method takes a starting index and a length.  You are passing in two indices.